# bypassing interactive mode detection in python

Tags: python

I am importing a third party package and that causes some statements to get printed on the console, jupyter notebook etc because inside the `__init__.py` of that package there is a call like:

```
if hasattr(sys,'ps1'):
    print('hello world')
```

Is there any way I could circumvent this from my end?

Comment: You could just comment out that code.

Comment: You could do `del sys.ps1`, but then you won't get an interpreter prompt.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments, deleting `sys.ps1` is an option.

```
del sys.ps1
```

If you want to go for a slightly less permanent (though still somewhat risky) solution, you can (ab)use Python's testing framework to temporarily remove the variable.

```
import sys
from unittest import mock

with mock.patch.dict('sys.__dict__'):
    del sys.ps1
    import whatever_library

# Outside of the 'with' block, sys.ps1 has its original value.
```

Not shown here: You should add an *extremely* lengthy comment explaining why this unusual code pattern is necessary, what it accomplishes, and what the risks are.

Comment: ah ok, thanks. That was new to me, `del sys.ps1` looks to work, need to think about the side effects now!